# Task.ContinueWith and async (core 3.1)

Tags: c#, async-await, .net-core-3.1

My code is similar to this:

```
    public async Process()
    {
        try
        {
            var records = await this.provider.GetRecordsAsync(); // this method can throws 'DataStoreException' only
    
            foreach(var record in records)
            {
                try
                {
                    this.Do(record); // here is some exception and code goes to catch
                    record.Status = Status.Success;
                    await this.provider.UpdateAsync(record).ContinueWith(
                        task =>
                        {
                            task.Exception?.Handle(e =>
                            {
                                this.logger.LogError(e);
                                return true;
                            });
                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
                }
                catch(Exception e)
                {
                    record.Status = Status.Error;
/*line 106:*/           await this.provider.UpdateAsync(record).ContinueWith(
                        task =>
                        {
                            task.Exception?.Handle(e =>
                            {
                                this.logger.LogError(e);
                                return true;
                            });
                        }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (DataStoreException e)
        {
            this.logger.LogError(e);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            // Got TaskCanceledException here
        }
    }
```

And at commented point I got `TaskCanceledException`. I suppose the reason are mixed `await` and `ContinueWith`, but can some one explain, what happened here? `UpdateAsync` can throw `DataStoreException` only. So `TaskCanceledException` thew by `ContinueWith`, but there is no cancellation tokens, code do not even reach this point `task.Exception?.Handle`

Here is the CallStack:

```
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at ProjectTest.MyClass.<Process>d__6.MoveNext() in C:\Projects\ProjectTest\MyClass.cs:line 106
```

If `try/catch` surrounds `this.provider.UpdateAsync(record)` instead of `ContinueWith` everything is good and code works as expected.
Does it actually bad practice to mix `await` and `ContinueWith` and if so, why?

Comment: As a side note, are you familiar with `finally` blocks?

Comment: Unless you are an expert and have a good reason for it, don't mix `ContinueWith` with `async-await`.

Answer (score 1):

The behavior you're seeing can be reproduced much more simply:

```
await Task.CompletedTask.ContinueWith(task =>
    {
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

`TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion` instructs the `ContinueWith` method to not execute the callback if the task completes successfully, and instead return a cancelled task.

You would use that option if you have a continuation that you specifically expect to run when an error occurs. For example:

```
await Task.FromException(new Exception()).ContinueWith(task =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task did not execute to completion");
    }, TaskContinuationOptions.NotOnRanToCompletion);
```

Since it looks like you expect `this.provider.UpdateAsync(record)` might succeed, that's probably not the option you want to use.

Comment: The second goal of the question - is there any good posts about `ContinueWith` and `await`? All those i've found are superficial.
P.S. of course I'm familiar with `try/finally`, the code above just an example, and real code has different exception handling :)

Comment: @Jonik: I don't have any posts to recommend specifically. Paulo is right: `async`/`await` should be your default. Not only does it make your code more idiomatic and straightforward: It does a lot of compilation magic behind the scenes to ensure things like stack traces are handled better than you could realistically handle them. If you're ever doing something _really complicated_ so you need to manage task continuations manually, that's when you'll want to read all the documentation and learn the ins and outs of methods like ContinueWith.